# SQL Perfomance: Retrieve Many Data Once VS Retrieve Less Data Many Times

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

I am new in SQL so forgive me if my question seems childish.

Just a brief description of my application:

1. I have a two table SQL database with table names: GUIelements, DataTable.
2. The GUIelements table is a very small 50 line table
3. The DataTable is a very big table with like 300000 entries
4. I also have have a C# application in which I have a Dynamically generated GUI based on the data available in GUIelements.
5. The C# application has a function which runs in a separate thread from the GUI, and the purpose of this function is to continuously (every 1 sec) monitor the GUIelements table to see if there is a change in the table. I do this by each time opening a connection, querying and closing the connection.

Everything works fine, the GUI updates as it should and I can also make queries in the Database from the main thread of the GUI. Everything seems perfect.

==============================

Now I would like to create another function which will be running again in another thread which will run every 10 minutes.
The purpose of this function will be to retrieve all the entries of the DataTable and once it retrieve them to a local list then do some low level processing like take the avg of the data.

My Questions is:

Is it better to retrieve from the sql database the whole DataTable once, store it in a temp list and do the processing:

```
USING()    
{    
 - OpenConnection
 - Query & Store data in a big 300000 elements list
 - Close Connection
 - Process list    
}
```

Or it will be better to retrieve the data from the DataTable in packets, process each packet and then request for the next packet. The operation will look like this:

```
FOR LOOP 3 TIMES    
USING()    
{    
 - OpenConnection
 - Query & Store data in a small 100000 elements list
 - Close Connection
 - Process list    
}    
END
```

Which approach will be better?

Is there any danger that some queries will fail because of multi-threading?

Please keep in mind the table and list sizes are not the actual, but I use these numbers as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have memory to store the whole data, then is better do it in one connection. To avoid the multiple network roundtrip. So the solution depend on your real size numbers.

But if you need the `AVG`, do it on the db not in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry but my example was oversimplified. I don't do just average, I do much more so I need to bring the actual data from the DB... Now the data are like several thousand entries but  in one month they could be several million. So if the returned data could be very big, is the second approach better?

Comment: Again the problem isnt the transfer of data, the problem is how are you going to store it in your app because depend how much memory you have available. And even if you need do much more calculations do it on your db using one store procedure. The only case where you must download all the data if is you doing a list of items and in that case you should do a pagination UI.

Comment: I tough in another scenary where you want download all the data. In case you want offline functionality, but for that you use a local db with replication functions.